# Discard regex match if certain word appears immediately before

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm completely unexperienced with regex, so I apologise if this is a simple question, but I've been unable to find any answers anywhere. I'm trying to match strings of the form `[some numbers] [some letters]` such as `123 apples` but I don't want to match them when they are preceeded by the word `about` (e.g. `about 10 apples` should not match).

I've tried using `(?<!about )(\d[,\.\d]*) ([a-zA-Z]+)` but that obviously doesn't work as it just moves the match on somewhat (such that `about 12 apples` matches as `2 apples`). What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  Try this:

```
(?<!about )(\b\d[,\.\d]*\b) ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

The `\b` matches a zero-character word boundary (space followed by alphanumeric or vice-versa).  It will refuse to match "about 123 apples" as "23 apples", because there's no word boundary immediately before the "2".

Comment: @LevLevitsky, my solution uses a variable length look-behind `(?<=\d*)`, which python's 're' module does not support.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close:   `(?<!about \d*)(\d[,\.\d]*)`.  Add `\d*` to your negative look behind.

Comment: Is the OP using python?  Some regex flavors support variable length look-behind expressions.